# How do I reindex my dataframe and also apply some of the operations or transformation on that data at the same time i am performing reindexing

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried by this piece of code, but its not working for me

```
import pandas as pd
Df1=pd.DataFrame({Price:[10,20,30,40],Company:['Abcd','Efgh','Ijkl','mnop'],City:['Delhi','Bangalore','Bombay','Chennai']})
Df2=Df1.reindex(index=[0,2],columns=['Price',Company],Df1['Price'].fill_value=Df1['Price']*12)
print(Df2)
```

My Expected output is this :

```
Price   Company
10*12     Abcd
30*12     Efgh
```

A quick help is really appreciated.
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: this is unclear to me without further explanation

Answer (score 0):

not sure your expected output is correct and worded correctly. 
3 assumptions;

1. 10*12 should be 120 ?
2. corresponding Price values should be used? (so 20 and not 30 for Company 'Efgh')
3. you want the first 2 (or first 'x') rows? or any slice? (rather then condition based)

You could create the new dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.DataFrame({'Price':[10,20,30,40],'Company':['Abcd','Efgh','Ijkl','mnop'],'City':['Delhi','Bangalore','Bombay','Chennai']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Price': Df1['Price'][0:2] * 12, 'Company': df1['Company'][0:2]})
print(df2)
Out: 
     Price Company
0    120    Abcd
1    240    Efgh
```

Comment: Ur assumptions are correct to my requirements but i want the same set of output using the reindex() method operations